# node.js callback value trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js

My issue is downloading images with unknown extension( it may be 'png' or 'jpg' or 'bmp' or etc...).And I have some troubles with function chekHead's returning value:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');
var processImg = function (uri,filename){
    if(checkHead(uri + 'png') > 2000){
        download(uri + 'png', filename + '.png', function(){
            console.log(uri + 'png' + " - downloaded")
        })
    }else if(checkHead(uri + 'jpg') > 2000){
        download(uri + 'jpg', filename + '.jpg', function(){
            console.log(uri + 'jpg' + " - downloaded")
        })
    }else if(checkHead(uri + 'bmp') > 2000) {
        download(uri + 'bmp', filename + '.bmp', function () {
            console.log(uri + 'bmp' + " - downloaded")
        })
    }

}


var checkHead = function(uri){
    var length;
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
        if(err) return console.log("Error");

        length = res.headers['content-length'];
        console.log(length);
    });
    return length;
}


var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./static/' + filename).on('close', callback));
};
```

So in **checkHead** function *return length;* always returns 'underfined', but console.log returns valid number; Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a callback so that is works the way you want it:

```
var checkHead = function(uri,callback){
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
        if(err) return console.log("Error");

        var length = res.headers['content-length'];
        console.log(length);
        callback(length);
    });
};
```

Unfortunately because of your if-else logic I see no way at the moment to use promises(jquery) instead of callbacks and nested callbacks that can lead to callback-hell that is kind of bad pattern so I say sorry for this:

```
checkHead(uri + 'png',function(length){
   if(length > 2000){
      download(uri + 'png', filename + '.png', function(){
        console.log(uri + 'png' + " - downloaded")
      });
   }
   else{  
      checkHead(uri + 'jpg',function(length){
         if(length > 2000){
            download(uri + 'jpg', filename + '.jpg', function(){
               console.log(uri + 'jpg' + " - downloaded")
            });
         }
         else{
            checkHead(uri + 'bmp',function(length){
                if(length > 2000){
                    download(uri + 'jpg', filename + '.jpg', function(){
                         console.log(uri + 'jpg' + " - downloaded")
                    });
                }
            });
         }
      });
   }

});
```

**BUT**
EcamScript 6 takes care of that. This is a good [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generators-preventing-callback-hell/) about Generator Functions. And the main idea is to use yield for asynchronous methods or functions like *request.head*:

```
var checkHead = function*(uri){
    var length = yield request.head(uri);
};
```

And use next to get length:

```
checkHead.next();//{value: 123, done: true}
```

This is only my concept i did not prove this but Generator Functions notations work in this way :)

Comment: Thx,got it . But how I can use my if/else statements, for image extenstion manipulatiion

Comment: wow, very appreciate). I think I can rule that with async.waterfall

Comment: Yes, absolutely it actually must be avoided but ES6(EcmaScript 6) takes care of that soon. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

NodeJS executes your code in an asynchronous way using callbacks. Your return could happen *before* (in this case it's probably always the case) the callback is completed. The variable `length` is at the `return`  undefined, because it hasn't received any values.

You could use promises to chain the function or you structure your code in another way.

For promises see e.g.:
[async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)
[q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)

```
var checkHead = function(uri){
    var length;

    // Callback is probably invoked after the return
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
        if(err) return console.log("Error");

        length = res.headers['content-length'];
        console.log(length);
    });

   // gets executed directly
    return length;
}
```